# SocketIo and Redis Multiple Emit Handling

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

I am trying to create a notification system that stores and displays real-time notifications to users, but I can't seem to figure out how to store and display more than one notification for an individual user with my current Socket-Io and Redis setup. Part of the reason why I can't achieve this might be my due to my lack of experience with Redis and the Pub/Sub functionality, but I'm not sure if I need to make adjustments to the SocketIo and Redis store relationship or that this is something that is typically handled outside of these modules with something like an array.

Here is my server-side code:

```
    var redisAdapter = require('socket.io-redis');
    var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);
    io.adapter(redisAdapter({
        host: process.env.REDIS_ENDPOINT || 'localhost',
        port: 6379
    }));
    var userNotification = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

        io.of('/').adapter.clients((err, clients) => {
            console.log("Socket IO Clients")
            console.log(clients); // an array containing all connected socket ids
        });

        socket.emit('notification', userNotification);


        //Client Notification
        socket.on('client-notification', function(data) {
          userNotification.data = data;
         });
});
```

Client-Side:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');  
    socket.on('notification', function (data) {

     console.log(data);
   });
});
```

With the current setup, the following socket client ids are generated, but I'm not sure how to interpret.

1) A session begins

```
[ 'GMs7nTrAHQ4z9o7KAAAC' ]
```

2) A user submits the form triggering `notification`

```
[ 'GMs7nTrAHQ4z9o7KAAAC', 'e4U1kcC6Jg0Ey45IAAAD' ]
```

3) Page is refreshed or new page is loaded. `notification` now appears in the navigation bar

```
[ '_T8oFXhrUyfwWpjqAAAF' ]
```

Here is the response from running `PUBSUB CHANNELS` with the redis-cli:

```
1) "socket.io-response#/#"
2) "socket.io-request#/#"
```

Comment: you are emitting one notification when the client connects. When do you want the other notifications to be emitted?

Comment: @mihai I would want the other notifications to be emitted whenever the form is submitted that triggers the client-side `notification`

Comment: then you should add a `socket.emit` in your `client-notification` callback. you are just doing `userNotification.data = data;` there, this does't send anything on the socket.

Comment: @mihai I made your adjustment, but the client is now not receiving any emits from the server. Are you sure I should be able to emit within `socket.on('client-notification', function(data) {}`?

Comment: I was thinking you should have anoter emit in there, without deleting the current emit.

Comment: Do you mind providing an example? Are you saying the `socket.emit` in the `client-notification` would have a different event name?

Comment: @mihai I see what you mean now and brought the emit within `client-notification` which allowed me to send the notification again, but when I refresh the page the notification is now lost. Do I need to create a room to store these notifications? Does the fact that the connected socket ID changes on a refresh point to the reason why the notification disappears?

Comment: yes, you would need some kind of persistance layer for your notifications, socket.io is meant for real-time communication and connections won't last beyond page refresh. Please ask a different question if you need help in this regard, I will add an answer for this question with the discussed changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently emitting only one notification when the client connects. To emit notifications for each `client-notification` event, use something along these lines:

```
var redisAdapter = require('socket.io-redis');
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

io.adapter(redisAdapter({
    host: process.env.REDIS_ENDPOINT || 'localhost',
    port: 6379
}));

var userNotification = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

    io.of('/').adapter.clients((err, clients) => {
        console.log("Socket IO Clients")
        console.log(clients); // an array containing all connected socket ids
    });

    socket.emit('notification', userNotification);

    //Client Notification
    socket.on('client-notification', function(data) {
        userNotification.data = data;

        socket.emit('notification', userNotification);
    });
});
```